# Jquery and binding an event to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I'm currently using a jquery textselect plugin to fire alerts based on the selection text anywhere on the page
and it works just fine doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind('textselect', function(e) {
        alert(e.text); 
    });
});
```

I've since had to add an iframe to the page and I need the text selection to work on text within the 
iframe as well. I'm trying to do something like this but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iframeId').load(function() {
    $(document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow).bind('textselect',function(e) {
    alert(e.text); 
    });
});
```

At this point I've tried a whole mess of ways to reference the iframe document without any success.  Any ideas?**

Answer (score 5):

You can access it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iframeId').load(function() {
    alert("Loaded");
    $('#iframeId').contents().find("body").bind('textselect', function(e) {
      alert(e.text);
    });
  });
});
```

Note: This only works if the iframe is loading something on the same domain, otherwise you're going to be blocked by the same origin policy.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  This is the plugin being used. 

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/textselect

Comment: @dbr - Updated the answer with a different approach, but I've rarely used custom events in a frame, not sure how it will behave.

Comment: This actually does launch the alert on text select of iframe content.  However, in order for it to work, the selected text has to be on the parent page.  Selecting text on the iframe doesn't do anything unless text is ALREADY pre-selected on the parent page.  e.text is bringing back the parent selection and not the iframe selection.  Is there a way to focus the event "e" to the iframe rather than the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing just for reference... What you sent worked.  The original function is passing in a document object.  For an `iframe` document object I did something like:

```
window.frames["ifFrameName"].document
```